# rich:dataTable zebra cells with css

Tags: java, css, datatable, richfaces

I'm using a rich:dataTable and I want every other cell to have a different color (zebra color effect). How can I implement this in my .css file?

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{uploader.files}" var="_data" id="files">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="File name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{_data.name}" />
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every cell should have a css class (`.rf-cst-c` it is in the actual [richfaces showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&skin=blueSky)), so you could do something like:

```
.rf-cst-c:nth-child(odd) td {
        background: #000;
}
.rf-cst-c:nth-child(even) td {
        background: #5b5b5b;
}
.rf-cst-c:nth-child(3n) td {
        background: #fff;
}
```

If the css class is changing due to different versions of rich faces, it should be no problem to use your browser's debugging tools and get hold of the css class in use.

Comment: The docs also tell you the table has `rowClasses` attribute. (Also RF 3.3.x are old, you should assume people are using RF 4)

Comment: well, okay. He didn't point out the version, so I thought it does not necessarily matter. The point is to get the classname for the cells that are generated and then be able to use the :nth-child selector to color them. I edited my answer anyways.

Comment: My point is that you don't need pseudoclasses you can just use `rowClasses="black,white"` and you're set.

Comment: Ok, I get it.I have not worked with any faces related yet, I was just reading the question "How can I implement this in my .css file?" and figured my answer would be ok. In fact you should post your anser, get a +1 from me and @user3463299 will mark it as accepted... (Although he was asking for cells, not rows)